# Storing float to database previously escaped as string? - safe?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, escaping

Other Q&Answers say that if you want to escape and store float with PDO you should use string escaping...(PDO::PARAM_STR)...

But is it really safe and propper way to escape FLOAT through PDO as STRING while storing it into FLOAT column in database(MySQL)? are these two floats "compatible"?
Should I pre-validate the float in PHP / or MySQL will just somehow convert the string to float even if it really isnt a float representation (but some random string)?

Comment: If it doesn't begin with a number, MySQL will convert it to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe in terms of SQL injection to do something like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue('foo', 1.23456, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Because this is safe for *any* value, regardless of its type.

It is also "safe" to want to store a string in a `float` MySQL column. You cannot store anything but a `float` in a `float` column, MySQL will coerce any value it receives into a `float` according to its casting rules. This may or may not trigger some error or warning, but a string → float conversion is pretty straight forward and should not cause any problems.

It's all "safe" in terms of security.

If your float is actually a float, it's also safe for the value. It's just being transported as a string, but the value itself will be transported. There *may* be tiny rounding errors with a `float` → `string` → `float` cast, as you'll always have to consider with floats.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer, you really got what I was asking and what security problems I would like to precede :) :)  PS: I am aware of float>string>float possible rounding problems, but its good to note that for others :)